# How to pass session variable inside class

Tags: php

I have a php variable that looks like this.

```
#Get the data from parameters
$startdate = $_GET['startdate']; 
$enddate   = $_GET['enddate']; 
$fspcode   = $_GET['fspcode']; 
$gl_codes  = $_GET['gl_codes'];
```

My question is how can I pass that in a class that looks like this?

```
#Create class.
class PDF extends FPDF
{   

function LoadData() {
  }
}
```

my target is to put those variable inside `function LoadData()`

Comment: pass the variables as arguments of the function

Comment: @Anandhunadesh how can I achive that sir. sorry for asking its my 1st time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to it

```
 <pre>
<?php
$startdate = "startdate"; 
$enddate   = "enddate"; 
$fspcode   = "fspcode";
$gl_codes  = "gl_codes";
class FPDF{

}
class PDF extends FPDF
{   

function LoadData($startdate=NULL,$enddate=NULL,$fspcode=NULL,$gl_codes=NULL) {
      echo $gl_codes;
  }
}
```

Create an instance of your class(PDF) and then call the method(LoadData) with parameters

```
$ff= new PDF;
$ff->LoadData($startdate,$enddate,$fspcode,$gl_codes);

?>
 </pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare the class declare it with the expecting number of parameters

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{   

function LoadData($param1,$param2,$param3,$param4) {// 4 parameters in your case.
  }
}
```

when you call the function pass the values that you have in session

```
LoadData($startdate,$enddate,$fspcode,$gl_codes)
```

Comment: Little late by couple of second but great help tysm